# Change JsonProperty name when serializing a object using JSON.Net Serializer

Tags: .net, vb.net, json, json.net

I have:

```
Public Class Ticket
  Private _ITicketStyle as ITicketStyle
  Public Property TicketStyle() as ITicketStyle
    Get
      Return _ITicketStyle
    End Get
    Set(value as ITicketStyle)
      _ITicketStyle = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class

Public Class FlightTicket
    Implements ITicketStyle
    Public Property city() as String
End Class

Public Class MovieTicket
    Implements ITicketStyle
    Public Property name() as String
End Class
```

with:

```
Dim ft as New Ticket()
ft.Ticket = New FlightTicket With { .city="NY" }
Dim output1 as String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ft)
```

I get : `output1 = {"TicketStyle":{"city" : "NY"}}`

and with:

```
Dim mt as New Ticket()
mt.Ticket = New MovieTicket With { .name="Transformers" }
Dim output2 as String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mt)
```

I get: `output2 = {"TicketStyle":{"name" : "Transformers"}}`

but I need:

```
output1 = {"FlightTicket":{"city": "NY"}} and 
output2={"MovieTicket": {"name": "Transformers"}}
```

Is there any way to achieve this one? I can apply `JsonProperty("FlightTicket")` to `TicketStyle` Property but need to change it to "MovieTicket" when `MovieTicket` object is assigned to `TicketStyle` property.

Comment: @Romoku, C# community is larger compared to vb.net and most of the programmers will answer JSON related questions irrespective language. That is the reason I used C# tag.

Comment: Added it to .NET so you get the best of both worlds.